# What does this button do in the iTunes device sync status bar?

Tags: itunes, ios

When an iPhone is plugged in and syncing, the status bar shows a message like:

> Syncing "Phone" (Step 2 of 6)

On the left side of the bar there is this icon:

[image]

It darkens when clicked, which implies that it's a button. If I had to guess from the icon alone, I would say "rotate clockwise", but that doesn't make sense in this context.

Hovering does not display a tooltip. Clicking it does not have any visible effect.

What is this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the skip button for skipping the current process. The button usually only shows on skippable actions and is most commonly shown for an iOS device iTunes backup.

Comment: Makes sense. Any idea why clicking it doesn't skip the current process?

Comment: @Robert Most likely a bug, in that it shouldn't be shown when it's not possible to skip.